# how to solve the java.io.IOException: failed to load image contents for serialization of jcchart in ByteArrayOutputStream

Tags: java, serialization, applet, jcchart

HI to all I am trying below for serializing a JCChart object in ByteArrayOutputStream

```
ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream() ;
            ObjectOutput out=new ObjectOutputStream(bos);
            out.writeObject(chart2);
            out.flush();
            out.close();
            ObjectInputStream in=new ObjectInputStream(new 

ByteArrayInputStream(bos.toByteArray()));
                chart_clone=(MyGraph)in.readObject();
                in.close();
```

but this code gives exceptione that java.io.IOException: failed to load image contents

can any body tell me where is the problem and how to solve this

Comment: Which line throws the exception? Can you add the trace?

Comment: out.writeObject(chart2); throws Exception. java.io.IOException: failed to load image contents
 at javax.swing.ImageIcon.writeObject(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(Unknown Source)

Actually the image icones image is unable to load when I try  
System.out.println(chart.ImageStatus);
then it prints false

Comment: @user571616 - Can you add the trace from your code till the `java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(...` call and also specify which method in your code is the one that "triggered" this?
Better edit the post instead of comments.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and the solution by Ali ([https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6029144/how-to-solve-the-java-io-ioexception-failed-to-load-image-contents-for-serializa/6712774#6712774](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6029144/how-to-solve-the-java-io-ioexception-failed-to-load-image-contents-for-serializ/6712774#6712774)) was very helpful..

ImageIcon is serializable (Image isn't thoguh). However, I forgot to copy the image that was being used in one of my ImageIcon objects into the right directory, and then I got this error.

Make sure the filepath exists before serializing an image that isn't really there!! :P

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are encountering the same issue as the one mentioned in this [OTN Post](http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=1150039&tstart=240).

The resolution there was to mark all Images which were members of the serialized object to be `transient` - meaning they will not be serialized. If your `chart` object has members of the type `ImageIcon`, it can solve your problem (and explain the stacktrace).

**Edit:** Keep in mind that not serializing the images might not be what you want if their content is dynamic and user defined, in which case you will loose their content when de-serializing. But I assume from the context that they are constants and can be ignored during serialization.

Comment: I already have seen that OTN Post but does not help me, how can I mark images transient while they are part of Multichart class. I does not have declared those images in my class. actually I am trying to clone the object of a class which is subclass of multichart, since by just cloning my class does not clone all the object whole object for that deep cloning is required . but many of the reference  like Legends , Footer does not support cloning so I becoming unable to deep cloning that's why I decide to serialize the object by ByteArrayOutputStream and then deserialize

Comment: no images can not be ignored they are the main thing which I required after serialization

Comment: Did you check the Load Status? `image.getImageLoadStatus()`?

Comment: no I did not put the check for image.getImageLoadStatus() but If I print System.out.println(chart.ImageStatus) before this process then it shows it false can u please tell me how can I load the image

Comment: I see my code again actually ImageStatus is my own variable which I use for to see tha status of image which is wrong. Please tell me another way to load the image for chart.

Comment: The status can either be:
1 - Loading
2 - Aborted
4 - Error
8 - Complete.

Which one is it?

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem, when I tried to write an object which has an ImageIcon into a file. it was due to the bad file address for the constructor of the ImageIcon and so it couldn't be written into the file using serialization.